# Why do alkenes react with oxidising agents?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, bond

My book says :

> The high electron density associated with the double bond means that
>   alkenes are attacked by oxidising agents.

And I dont understand how the high electron density in the double bond causes that.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, oxidation is loss of electron(s) by any species and an oxidising agent is an acceptor of electron(s). So, high electron density on alkenes make them likely to be attacked by oxidising agents.

Comment: What you are saying surely does make sense to me but the full sentence is "The high electron density associated with the double bond means that the alkenes are attacked by both electrophiles and oxidising agents." This implies that electrophiles and oxidising agents are two different things but your definition of an oxidising agent applies to both electrophiles and oxidising agents so if they are the same thing why would the book mention them in that way and make them appear as two different things ?

Comment: @Sam19KY First of all you didn't mentioned about electrophiles. And by the way, any electron deficient species always searches for electron rich species.

Comment: yeah i didnt mention the electrophiles bcz i understood that part ( i know that positive species are attracted to electrons) but now i had to bring it up because of what i said in the 1st comment